# ZF2 ODM MongoDB "need to login"

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, zend-framework2, odm

i'm using ZF2 with ODM and MongoDB. When i try to perform very simple tasks like:

```
/** @ODM\Document(collection="Test") */
class Test
{
   ...
}
```

I receive the Error "need to login". Well, i know why this is a problem an i can solve it by using:

```
/** @ODM\Document(db="mongoDB", collection="Test") */
class Test
{
   ...
}
```

Instead of using the db declaration the whole time in every class, is there a way to add config values from the .local/.global config file or can i just reconfigure the configure options?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read through [this useful tutorial](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/) about implementing Doctrine with ZF2. You should be placing global configuration options in Module.php and config/local.php. This array key in Module.php:

```
'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

And these DB connection parameters in local.php:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => '',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname'   => 'zf2tutorial',
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

This will allow you to avoid repetition in your DB entities, allowing you to use just the following Doctrine declarations for each of your classes:

```
/**
 * A music album.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="album")
 * @property string $artist
 * @property string $title
 * @property int $id
 */
class Album implements InputFilterAwareInterface {
```